# reloading properties after updating a property file

Tags: ant, properties

I'm trying to read a property after updating it using propertyfile task. Something like

```
<property file="test.properties" />
<echo>before :: ${modules}</echo>

<propertyfile file="test.properties" >
   <entry key="modules" type="string" operation="+" value="foo" />
</propertyfile>

<property file="${status.path}/test.properties" />
<echo>after :: ${modules}</echo>.
```

It doesn't seem to load the second time. But the property file is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sudocode already mentioned, in Core Ant properties are immutable - for good reasons.
With the [unset](http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03ch08.html) task from [Antelope Ant Task](http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03.html)s you're able to unset all properties set in a file with a one liner :

```
<unset file="test.properties"/>
```

afterwards

```
<propertyfile file="test.properties" >
   <entry key="modules" type="string" operation="+" value="foo" />
</propertyfile>
```

will work.

Hint : the task works only for normal properties, not for xmlproperties.
But there's a simple workararound, simply use
 `<echoproperties prefix="..." destfile="foo.properties"/>` 
and afterwards
 `<unset file="foo.properties"/>` 
If you don't want to use Antelope for that specific task only, you may write a macrodef or own task with similar features.

Answer (score 7):

You can invoke a new ant runtime with the `antcall` task that ignores the properties of your main target runtime - just make sure to include `inheritAll="false"`

```
<target name="main">
    <property file="test.properties"/>
    <echo>before :: ${modules}</echo>

    <propertyfile file="test.properties">
        <entry key="modules" type="string" operation="+" value="foo" />
    </propertyfile>

    <antcall target="second-runtime" inheritAll="false"/>
</target>

<target name="second-runtime">
    <property file="${status.path}/test.properties" />
    <echo>after :: ${modules}</echo>
</target>
```

[antcall refrence](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html)

Answer (score 1):

For this case, when whole properties file is loaded twice, I suggest using different prefixes for the first and second load. First **load with a`prefix` attribute** equal to `first`. Access the properties with this prefix, that is property `foo` will be accessible as `first.foo`. Then save the properties file and load again, but this time without a prefix. You will get modified properties in suitable place.

Without using the prefix the second load will do nothing, as ant prevents properties from overriding. Others pointed that already.

Answer (score 0):

Ant properties are immutable - once set, they are fixed. So reloading the properties file will not refresh the value of a property already set.

Answer (score 0):

this macro allow you to change the property value after fixed one

```
<macrodef name="set" >
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <sequential>
        <script language="javascript">
            <![CDATA[
            project.setProperty("@{name}", "@{value}");
            ]]>
        </script>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new properties file and save the property in the new file.

Provide the reference of the file in the next line.

Done :)